# Run method as time updates

Tags: swift

I am making an app that tells users the time until the next bus comes. As the time changes it will be different to the time that was registered in `viewDidLoad`. How can I constantly update the time?

Comment: Well, use a Timer: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer

Comment: You can subclass UILabel, create a TimerLabel and add a timer to it so it can auto update its contents